# APACHE2: How to write log for a specific directory requested?

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files

I have this line in the virtual host:

```
CustomLog /var/log/access.log combined
```

But I want a specific log to write each request of a specific directory

e.g.

I have this sub directories in my public:

```
user@/var/www # ls
index.test  images/ test.php
```

How to write a log when the users make a request any file inside `images` dir?

**Edit:** The main idea for this is to prevent the main log file to grow a lot and to simplify the searches

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try setting environment variables.

Eg.

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/images(/|$) imageslog

CustomLog /var/log/images-access.log combined env=imageslog
```

> The third argument is optional and controls whether or not to log a
>   particular request based on the presence or absence of a particular
>   variable in the server environment. If the specified environment
>   variable is set for the request (or is not set, in the case of a
>   `'env=!name'` clause), then the request will be logged.
>
> Environment variables can be set on a per-request basis using the
>   `mod_setenvif` and/or `mod_rewrite` modules. For example, if you want to
>   record requests for all GIF images on your server in a separate
>   logfile but not in your main log, you can use:
>
> ```
> SetEnvIf Request_URI \.gif$ gif-image
> CustomLog gif-requests.log common env=gif-image
> CustomLog nongif-requests.log common env=!gif-image
> ```
>
> Or, to reproduce the behavior of the old RefererIgnore directive, you
>   might use the following:
>
> ```
> SetEnvIf Referer example\.com localreferer
> CustomLog referer.log referer env=!localreferer
> ```

See also: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html

I hope this help

Comment: the `imageslog` in the `SetEnvIf` line is the name of the environment? I mean, is like setting the name that I'm going to specific in the `env=` space?

Comment: Yes, in the line `SetEnvIf` you set a env var named `imageslog` and in the line `CustomLog` you accept log reguest only if `env=imageslog` exist.

Comment: This still writes in the main log, sorry if a don't specify this in the question, I will edit

Comment: Add in the main log config env=!imageslog to prevent log request to images